# Added changes are gone after accidental "git push"

Tags: git

Relatively new to using GitHub and am running into an annoying issue.

I made a new branch, added my changes, and committed them. Then I used `git push` instead of `git push origin master` and I received an error:

`fatal: The current branch branch_name has no upstream branch.`

Now when I type `git status`, my changes are gone and when I try `git push origin master` it tells me everything is up to date. I've checked the master and my current working branch and they are still different. I don't know how to get my changes back so I can add the branch to GitHub.

Comment: By the way, sorry this isn't more timely but I just noticed that you already followed the advice from Pankaj Gadge's answer... Well, no doubt that caused `status` to start showing your changes again (because his reset told git to behave more or less like they hadn't been committed).  This being the case, you have to re-commit the changes before it's possible to push them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're misinterpreting the `git status` output.  It is not telling you that your changes are gone.  It is telling you that your current index and work tree are not changed with respect to your last commit - and that's simply because you committed your changes.

To see if your changes are still there, you would use something like `git show` (to see the current commit's changes relative to the previous commit) or `git log -p` (to see a running history of changes in the current history).

So yes your first push failed, but that only means that you still have to complete the correct `push` command.  The full error message from the failed command would read

```
fatal: The current branch foo has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin <branch-name>
```

where `<branch-name>` is the name of your branch.

The reason that `git push origin master` says everything's up to date is that you don't have any changes on `master` to push.  If what you mean to do is add your changes to `master` and then push them to the remote on `master`, then the most straightforward thing is to merge them to `master` locally and then `git push origin master` will work.

But if you're just trying to have the remote know about your branch (while still keeping it separate from `master`) then you can use `git push --set-upstream origin <branch-name>`

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted, but this is the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to `recover` your last commit using,

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

If you've made more than one commits then replace `1` with # of commits made.

Comment: That recovered my commit, but when I do `git push origin master` after adding and committing, it still tells me that everything is up to date. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Check out the `target` branch and see if it has your last commit? You might want to rebase onto the target branch.